# Is it problematic when using Newton Descent with discontinuous Hessian?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Is there any side effect when applying Newton Descent to a convex function whose Hessian is discontinuous?

Comment: What do you mean by side effect? (For example, applying Newton's method to smooth functions such as $x \mapsto x^4$ causes the rate of convergence to degenerate to linear.)

Comment: Thanks for your interest, @copper.hat. I mean any possibly undesired result, including but not confining to slow convergence. I wonder if it fails to converge for Newton Descent with discontinuous Hessian?

Comment: You would need to describe what you mean by 'Newton descent' in more detail. Is there a step size calculation involved?

Comment: Hi @copper.hat, to clarify what I mean I have post a new quesion to avoid the ambiguity of whether Newton's method denotes the one in convex optimization or the one in function's root finding. See the link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337729/when-finding-root-does-newtons-method-fail-if-the-function-is-non-differentiab