# When finding root, does Newton's method fail if the function is non-differentiable?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

According to [wikipedia's description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton-Raphson), the Newton's method finding a root presumes a differentiable function. Then, will it fail when encountering non-differentiable function? For example, can it find the zero-crossing point of a one-dimensional piecewise linear function?

---

I have found that this is actually an active topic in modern Operation Research or related domains (e.g., see the paper ["a nonsmooth version of Newton method" by L. Qi & J. Sun](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=A%20nonsmooth%20version%20of%20Newton%20method)  and the papers citing it therein).

Answer (score 4):

Newton's method is an iterative procedure, generating a sequence of numbers $\{x_0, x_1, \dots\}$.  In each case, we finding where the tangent line to the graph of the function at $(x_n, f(x_n))$ meets the $x$-axis in order to find $x_{n+1}$.

In many situations, this sequence converges to a root, but it *can* fail if

- $x_n$ for some $n$ is a non-differentiable point for $f$, or
- the sequence of approximations bounce around wildly without converging (for example, consider finding the root $x=0$ of $f(x) = x^{1/3}$, beginning with $x_0 \ne 0$.)

We cannot guarantee that Newton's method *will* fail for a piecewise linear function, but it *could.*

Comment: Thanks for your example, in particular the second one:-) Geometrically, I beleive Newton's method WILL succeed for convex (or concave) piecewise linear function and CAN fail for convex-concave mixed one (e.g., the piecewise approximation for $x^{1/3}$). Wondering if there is any quantative condition characterizing this intuitively true statement?

Answer (score 2):

Methods that do not require the derivative to be available
are the secant method, Aitken's method,
and Steffensen's method.

As with all iterative methods,
sometimes they work and sometimes they don't.